# Powershell and CMD prompt : Negative value multiplication problem

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I wrote powershell ps1 code which has `($args[0] * -1)` i.e variable with negative value multiplication. The code just breeze through when it is run in `powershell : .\myscript.ps1`.

During the scheduling of the script, it didn't work, so when I made it run in the run CMD prompt using `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "c:\myscript.ps1" 101 3`, it threw the error for `($args[0] * -1)` [negative mulitplication] and manually running it in cmd prompt gave the same problem.

So at that time, I made a little tweak to code accepting the negative value as attribute instead of it being multiplied in code to -1 and made it to run.

If future how to write ps1 code which does negative value multiplication and also runs in CMD prompt?

Comment: I can't replicate the error. For me works in console and called from a CMD.

Comment: Second christian and what is the exact error? Paste that in your question.

Comment: My best guess is that the problem is with $args being strings and not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the negative value input or command line but the problem was with the data type; As it was pointed out by JasonMArcher. A simple type cast did all the trick.